# How do I get the virtual terminal to show by default on startup?

Tags: startup, virtual-terminal

I've got an older system that's resource challenged. I've disabled/removed gdm and kdm, and removed the splash screen by editing `/etc/default/grub` and running `sudo update-grub`.

GDM doesn't start, and I don't get the splash screen. However, I'm left with

> Checking battery state                            [ OK ]

and I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to the virtual terminal. How can I make the startup process end at tty0?

(I'm running Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X (window server) is starting with no window manager and you need to change your default runlevel but cannot find the `/etc/inittab` file and there is no appropriate runlevel to use anyway, right? If you do not want to use the cleanest method of installing 10.04/10.10 server, then just tell GDM not to even try on runlevel 3:

```
sudo -e /etc/init/gdm.conf
```

Change `stop on runlevel [016]` to `stop on runlevel [0136]`

Save. Now set the default runlevel:

```
sudo -e /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
```

Change `env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2` to `env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=3`

Save and reboot: `sudo init 6`

Success?

Comment: No dice... I'm assuming that it's actually setting the runlevel since `runlevel` outputs 3. I don't /think/ it's so much a problem with gdm, since I just went ahead and uninstalled it.

Comment: After upgrading to 11.10 these changes were the same, and I changed `/etc/init/kdm.conf` to have `start on runlevel []`, and that fixed it.